# Aggregation pipeline for filtering the array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an array like:

```
const tags = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

and my collection looks like:

```
[{
  _id: asdsadasd,
  tagName: "a"
 },
 {
  _id: qweqewqe,
  tagName: "d"
 }
]
```

I want to filter the `tags` array such that it doesn't contain any of the tags(`tagName` field) in the collection.

sample output:

```
["b", "c"]
```

This is what I tried:

```
[
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': null, 
      'tags': {
        '$push': '$tagName'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'filteredTags': {
        '$filter': {
          'input': tags, 
          'as': 'item', 
          'cond': {
            '$not': {
              '$in': [
                '$$item', '$tags'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This is working fine but I want to know if there is a more efficient way to do this using aggregation pipeline or in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": { "$push": "$tagName" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "tags": {
      "$setDifference": [
        ["a", "b", "c"],
        "$data"
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2YAGCazf4Vq)